# how to bypass the 65535 character limit in a select statement using "FOR XML"

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am aware of the 65535 truncation for text datatypes (and Varchar(MAX) as well).  I am also aware of XML outputs that can be set to unlimited.  I have a table that stores XML strings in a varchar(MAX) column called GEOM.

My problem is that the xml snippet held in the geom column can exceed 65535 characters.  I figure since it's XML, and I'm creating an XML output in my code anyways, why not just build the xml and send that out as such, since I can set XML output to "Unlimited".

```
USE [buyerhero]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GEOIDKMLCOUNTY]    Script Date: 9/17/2015 11:18:55 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GEOIDKMLCOUNTY] @CountyID nvarchar(30)
AS
DECLARE @kml XML
DECLARE @kmlout NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @kml = CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>' + 
'<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">' + 
'<Document>' + 
'       <Style id="Licensed">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e1400FF</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="NotLicensed">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e14F0FF</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="Other">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e007800</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>' +
(
            select 
                '<![CDATA[{"County":"' + r.CountyName + ', ' + r.State + '", "GEOID": "'+t.GEOID+'"}]]>' as Name,
                case t.IsLicensed
                    when 2 then '#Licensed'
                    when 1 then '#NotLicensed'
                    else '#Other'
                end as StyleURL, 
                cast(replace(geom,'"','') as xml) as Geometry
        from Tracts t 
        join census_county_ref c on t.GEOID = c.GEOID
        join FIPSCountyCode r on c.STATEFP = r.StateANSI and c.COUNTYFP = r.CountyANSI
        where r.CountyID = @CountyID
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS) + '</Document></kml>' AS XML)
--
-- Perform replacement of &lt; and &gt; with < and > respectively
--
SET @kmlout = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@kml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>')
SET @kmlout = REPLACE(@kmlout, 'utf-16', 'utf-8')
--
-- Return kmlout
--
SELECT @kmlout
```

in spite of the idea the geom columns is xml and I'm using `cast(replace(geom,'"','') as xml)`  which is varchar(max), that field still gets truncated.

How do I "untruncate" the field so I can output the XML?

Thanks.

Comment: Well the text datatype shouldn't be used for anything. It has been deprecated for over a decade in favor of varchar(max). Not sure where you found the limit of varchar(max) being 65,535 characters. The actual limit is 2GB (2^31-1 bytes) which is something like 80 copies of War & Peace and should be sufficient for nearly anything you could possibly pass. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: That being said you could use the XML datatype instead of a character datatype. It has the bonus of validating you don't have garbage in your xml. :)

Comment: You don't have anything runnable, nor do you say how you know there's truncation, however, is it possible that you are simply seeing non-XML data truncated in the SQL Server Management Studio to 65535 characters? There is a setting for that in SSMS Tools|Options, but I think 65535 is the maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the concat function instead the + operator. the plus operator is limited to 8000 bytes.

```
SELECT @kml =CAST(concat('your xml', the select,'the other xml')
```

Comment: That was my problem.  Thanks. I appreciate the idea.  It helped me get the output I needed.